# Did anyone else get an attachment from the Super User newsletter?

Tags: discussion, email, newsletter

What in all actually is this PDF attachment doing with the newsletter?

[image]

I'm *fairly* confident that this also came from Stack Exchange, so would someone care to enlighten me as to what's going on?  I admit I'm rusty at reading mail headers, but the sources seem to line up just fine.

```
Delivered-To: --REDACTED--
Received: by 10.229.68.6 with SMTP id t6csp224071qci;
        Fri, 20 Mar 2015 12:28:47 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.55.31.97 with SMTP id f94mr119580342qkf.10.1426879727323;
        Fri, 20 Mar 2015 12:28:47 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <do-not-reply@stackexchange.com>
Received: from mx-out.stackexchange.com (mx-out.stackexchange.com. [198.252.206.125])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id i90si5136899qge.83.2015.03.20.12.28.46
        for <--REDACTED-->
        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Fri, 20 Mar 2015 12:28:47 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of do-not-reply@stackexchange.com designates 198.252.206.125 as permitted sender) client-ip=198.252.206.125;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of do-not-reply@stackexchange.com designates 198.252.206.125 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=do-not-reply@stackexchange.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@stackexchange.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=stackexchange.com; s=dk;
    h=Content-Type:Message-ID:Date:Subject:Reply-To:To:From:MIME-Version; bh=1OWPTURI/S9xuD+By0vS6qm84rNbZTEnVTBe0n3jV2Q=;
    b=VEwIjIH/yuaj1DiAJMIuXOs8vPo1fhJOHhM7v9IWtvRozVyDnMzZBeFVsaAiUDSmsMrXb8sH3X0TU2a94KkuzByGyong8s4pRn6CridgSwOJuQ1OLhN/zSNiSu00rPENBxFhmiABN0PNx8m6S8OZHwMMPob6SzQUm5IK1JsjFxY=;
Received: from [10.7.2.15] (helo=[10.7.2.101])
    by mx-out.stackexchange.com with esmtp (Exim 4.72)
    (envelope-from <do-not-reply@stackexchange.com>)
    id 1YZ0VC-0006l0-SY
    for --REDACTED--; Fri, 20 Mar 2015 17:14:30 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Mailer: MailBee.NET 7.0.4.334
From: "Stack Exchange" <do-not-reply@stackexchange.com>
To: --REDACTED--
Reply-To: do-not-reply@stackexchange.com
Subject: Super User Weekly Newsletter - Friday, March 20, 2015
Date: Fri, 20 Mar 2015 17:14:30 +0000
Message-ID: <2.9e47a33dae2ecd6e7599@NY-WEB01>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
```

Comment: haha, wat​​​​​​

Comment: Sighh, just fill in the paperwork...don't ask where it is for...please?

Comment: @rene:  As interesting as that may be, I can't deduct `asdasd` in...whatever currency that is from my bank account right now.  I mean, I *am* going on a business trip soon, so I've gotta keep a bit of cash in the bank for souvenirs...

Comment: This appears to be an XY problem, and you are asking the wrong question. What you *should* be asking is, "What the dues is what the deese how the doesn't doesn't dues?". Please show us how you determined that the doesn't doesn't dues, and what you have deesed to determine does does (or doesn't) the dues. We're not here to do your work for you.

Comment: I got a feeling this *wasn't really supposed to reach production and be sent*.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The PDF in question is linked to from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/889663/pdfs-as-extremely-small-file-size-i-e-less-than-20kb) in the form of a `drive.google.com` link. Judging by the [sample newsletter](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=superuser.com), the question was included in the newsletter you received.

> [image]

Gmail autodetects Google Drive links, and adds them as friendly attachments*.. which causes crazy in this particular, albeit pretty rare, instance.

---

<sup>* You can test this by including the link `https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6HXMKHljcfYV1d5Yl9YNzd4TWM/view?usp=sharing`, and sending it in an email to yourself, [like I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0GSE.png)</sup>

Comment: lol, so brilliant!

Comment: Nice work tracking this one down. What a hilariously bizarre occurrence.

Comment: Darn it Inbox...Thanks for the answer.  Strangely enough it did this with a newsletter that had a YouTube link, but it didn't register with me that it was GMail/Inbox being overzealous with its visibility.

Comment: Good job, Google.

Comment: Google is evil.