# Why does this question show up in the Frequently Asked Questions list if it isn't tagged [faq]?

Tags: support, meta, homepage, sidebar, meta-faq

Currently, the Frequently Asked Questions list on the Meta homepage looks like this:

> [image: faq list]

But the very first question on that list isn't tagged with [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) at all!

> [image: no [faq]!!!111!!!]

Is this a bug, or can questions without the special tag appear in that list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because it's featured. And that's how the FAQ list works on Meta: it includes [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) entries, and [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) posts.

This behavior predates the introduction of the Community Bulletin board, and no one has been bothered enough to change it.

Comment: Okay. That was straightforward. Is there any compelling reason to change it, or will Meta be a special snowflake for all eternity?

Comment: Regardless of whether or not we change this, meta will always be a "special snowflake".

Comment: @Alexis beware, [this snowflake](http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2012/229/1/5/snowflake___yeaahhh_by_rot_lunatik-d5bh7yg.png) might get angry if you keep using his name! :D

Comment: By the way Shog, just in case you missed it, looks like a [top secret invoice leaked out](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251749/did-anyone-else-get-an-attachment-from-the-super-user-newsletter)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Now everyone will know what the dues is what the deese how the doesn't doesn't dues?!

Comment: @Alexis yup, unless Mr. Shog will erase any trace of its existence... ;)

Comment: Similarly, right now "The Developer Story Part 2: We didn't explain that very well" is showing up as "frequently asked." Obviously this has only ever been "asked" once, and in fact it's not even a question. Is there a chance that "frequently asked" could at least be renamed to something that isn't self-evidently inaccurate as a description of that set of posts?