# What is the 10.7.2.15 entry in the history log of my SE Open ID account?

Tags: support, bug, login, user-accounts, stack-exchange-openid

I'm asking this question on behalf of my second account: [KennyBOT](//stackexchange.com/users/4933295/kennybot)

KennyBOT uses a Stack Exchange account and therefore logs in with the Stack Exchange Open ID provider which enables users to see their login and authentication history on [this page](https://openid.stackexchange.com/user).

The page contains the following entries in the history table:

```
Authenticated To    Authenticated to stackexchange.com          80.*.*.*    1 min ago
Login               Logged In                                   80.*.*.*    1 min ago
Authenticated To    Authenticated to data.stackexchange.com     80.*.*.*    2 days ago
Login               Logged In                                   80.*.*.*    2 days ago
Login               Logged In                                   10.7.2.15   Mar 19 at 11:27
Authenticated To    Authenticated to data.stackexchange.com     80.*.*.*    Mar 15 at 22:25
Login               Logged In                                   80.*.*.*    Mar 15 at 22:25
Authenticated To    Authenticated to stackoverflow.com          80.*.*.*    Mar 15 at 22:25
Login               Logged In                                   80.*.*.*    Mar 15 at 22:25
Authenticated To    Authenticated to data.stackexchange.com     80.*.*.*    Mar 15 at 21:58
Login               Logged In                                   80.*.*.*    Mar 15 at 21:58
Authenticated To    Authenticated to stackoverflow.com          80.*.*.*    Mar 15 at 21:57
Login               Logged In                                   80.*.*.*    Mar 15 at 21:57
```

The 80.* IP addresses are clear to me because that is my own IP address. But why and how did it manage to login from [10.7.2.15](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251749/did-anyone-else-get-an-attachment-from-the-super-user-newsletter) which is an internal-ip address within the SE-network server farm?

I [contacted the team](//meta.stackexchange.com/help/security-reports) over the weekend to rule out that the account was somehow compromised and in the response (<sub>ticket:Other - 201503211033317703</sub>) I learned that the account was **not** used on the sites from the 10.* address, only from my own 80.* address. They also directed me to check [How does SO's new auto-login feature work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260) and if questions remained to ask them here, so here we are:

**Who or what logged in with the account [KennyBot](//stackexchange.com/users/4933295/kennybot) from 10.7.2.15 and why did it do so?**

I use that account from a separate browser to prevent any mishaps with my normal account or from a .Net WebClient programmatically. On that particular day I didn't have any test-session going and I don't recall having used the other browser to login.

Comment: This kind of mistake with the logged IPs has happened in the past, I remember one instance where it was caused by SE trying out Cloudflare. My guess is that this is a bug somewhere in SE code that accidentally inserted an internal IP instead of your real one.

Comment: That sounds plausible. One other option I considered was an auto-logon from a still existing session but that would require the browser session to be still alive which I doubt was true.

Comment: Wow, what a story :) Has this happened since?

Comment: @nicael yes, but I didn't spend enough time on it to get a decent repro.

Comment: Same IP was logged when I logged in from https://stackoverflow.com/users/login. So I agree with Mad.

Comment: Wow, what a story :) Has this happened since?

Comment: Yes, I agree with the comment above.  It sounds like a VM issue.