# Stack Exchange newsletter wrong link

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, newsletter

Each week I receive Stack Exchange newsletter and each week I can't view the full article due to broken links like 
[this one](http://stackjava-script.com/questions/29343533/is-it-more-efficient-to-perform-a-range-check-by-casting-to-uint-instead-of-chec?newsletter=1&nlcode=289826%7C207a).

What's is wrong with the newsletter?

Comment: Looks like your local box is infected by a virus/malware

Comment: I only read them online on my provider webmail page.

Comment: That's not bug or issue with Stack Exchange. Something on your side is replacing "overflow" with "java-script", might be April Fools' prank of your ISP or email provider. The correct link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343533/is-it-more-efficient-to-perform-a-range-check-by-casting-to-uint-instead-of-chec?newsletter=1&nlcode=289826%7C207a which is just fine

Comment: There seems nothing wrong with the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343533/is-it-more-efficient-to-perform-a-range-check-by-casting-to-uint-instead-of-chec) and there aren't vague links in it that could explain behaviour link [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251749/did-anyone-else-get-an-attachment-from-the-super-user-newsletter)

Comment: do you have any 'april fools' extension or userscripts? Try opening the mail in incognito mode (If you have Chrome) or incognito's alternative for your browser...

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that's not coming from us:

[image]

As others have suggested, try turning off all browser extensions or using the incognito mode to see if the problem persists.